# Android - Wait for object execution to finish before continuing

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, execution, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPAndroidChart` to draw some charts in android. The problem I'm facing is that the following code is executed in asynchronous way. E.g:

```
Log.d("Starting data load","Starting data load");
x1.setValueFormatter(new GraphXAxisValueFormatter(xLabels_nl,chart));
chart.setData(data);
chart.fitScreen();
Log.d("Finished data load","Finished data load");
```

1. "Starting data load" is logged to console
2. `setValueFormatter` is initiated
3. "Finished data load" is logged to console
4. `setValueFormatter` is still running

The problem is that when `setValueFormatter` is still running, if the described code is executed second time, the chart does not `zoom/drag` correctly to it's initial position.
Is there a way to wait till the first execution of `"x1.setValueFormatter(new GraphXAxisValueFormatter(xLabels_nl,chart));"` is finished when it is started second time ?

The `GraphXAxisValueFormatter` is class that overrides the following method:

```
@Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
...
return <axis values for each point at position "value">
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is probably elsewhere, you should raise an issue on the open source library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues

**Hack Alert**
But you can make arbitrary code wait for you if you want:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Log.d("Starting data load","Starting data load");
final GraphXAxisValueFormatter graphFormatter = new GraphXAxisValueFormatter(xLabels_nl,chart)
x1.setValueFormatter(new IValueFormatter() {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
          String result = graphFormatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, dataSetIndex, viewPortHandler);
          latch.countdown();
          return result;
    }

});
try {
   latch.await(); // this will make this Thread wait until countdown() is called
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // uh oh, deal with error
}
chart.setData(data);
chart.fitScreen();
Log.d("Finished data load","Finished data load");
```

Note - you cannot make the MainThread wait too long or you will get an ANR (you shouldn't make it wait at all really)

Comment: Thanks for the solution proposed! I've raised this to mpandroidchart developer also and will update the thread here is there is another solution. One additional question: getFormattedValue is called multiple times (for each point from the chart). So latch.countdown will be called at each execution of getFormattedValue and the main thread will wait for each single execution to finish. Is there a way to make latch.countdown be executed only at the end of the process of executing all iterations of getFormattedValue ?

Answer (score 0):

MPAndroidChart classes like `LineChart` are subclasses of `View` and thus should be updated on the UI/main thread.

If you are performing processing of data on another thread (in, say, an `AsyncTask` or using RxJava) that is fine. However, modifications of the `View` object itself (such as mutating the `DataSet` or `IValueFormatter` for the chart) should be done on the UI/main thread or you will run into synchronisation problems like the one that seems to be occurring above. This is the standard pattern for *most* standard Android Views, not just MPAndroidChart. Note that none of the methods in `LineChart` etc. actually spawn another thread so it is the responsibility of the consumer to ensure they are using the correct thread.

Additionally, after you have updated the `DataSet` you will need to call `ChartData#notifyDataSetChanged();` to get the library to recalculate the min/max.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm not using any threads different from the main/UI thread. I removed all background executed code(load data from DB) in order to test. The issue is easily reproduceable by setting logging in the AxisValueFormatter and before and after chart is drawn. If I wait for the logging from AxisValueFormatter to be completed and then redraw the chart everything works fine.If I redraw the chart before the logging from AxisValueFormatter is completed, the draggind/zooming issues apper.I have placed a call to notifyDataSetChanged after setting the data.The issue still pesists.

Comment: @Kiril thanks for replying - rather than `setValueFormatter()` getting executed asynchronously (which seems unlikely since MPAndroidChart doesn't spawn a thread for this) I think what may be happening is the `onDraw()` is triggered prematurely. I'll try and have a look sometime